# CSS - transform:scale images overlapping and not scaling correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to recreate this [codepen](https://codepen.io/MikeWhitehead/pen/BJyZay) transform:scale transition for a particular page on my site but it's not working as it should - as you can see here on this code snippet (view on full page) - images over/under-lapping and jerky rather than smooth.

```css
/* Partners page */


.masonry { /* Masonry container */
    column-count: 5;
   
}




.brick img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

body {
    
    font-family: 'Gotham-Light';
    margin: 0;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 3em auto;
}

.masonry {
    margin: 1.5em 0;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.5em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em;
    column-gap: 1.5em;
    font-size: .85em;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.brick {
   display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Image words / text hover effect */ 

 .brick {
  
  opacity: .99;
  position: relative;
  
}




 .wrapper .brick .details {
  padding: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
   opacity: 0;
  transition: .7s ease;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,.9), rgba(0,0,0,0));
}

.brick:hover {
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
 -webkit-transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

 .brick:hover .details {
  opacity: 1;
} 


.brick .details span {
 
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0; /* 100px */
  -webkit-transition-property: top, opacity;
  transition-property: top, opacity;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
          transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
          transition-delay: 0s;
}

 .brick .details #title {
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
}

 .brick .details #info {
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.brick:focus:before,
  .brick:focus span, .brick:hover:before,
 .brick:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
  
}
 .brick:focus:before, .brick:hover:before {
  top: 0;  /* 50% */
 
}

 .brick:focus span, .brick:hover span {
  top: 0;
}
 .brick:focus #title, .brick:hover #title {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s;
          transition-delay: 0.25s;
}
 .brick:focus #info, .brick:hover #info {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s;
          transition-delay: 0.25s;
}

/* -------------------------   */
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="masonry">
       <div class="partner">
                    <a href="index.html"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509810535/Certo-120x72_hrw5eq.png" style="width: 180px; height: 120px;" class="partimg"></a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
                </div>
        <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449086/2brand_identity_oo9udc.jpg">
         <div class="details">
                           
                            <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna</span>
                        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449069/2print_zszssh.jpg">
         <div class="details">
                           
                            <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna</span>
                        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449077/2graphic_design_obcmif.jpg">
         <div class="details">
                           
                            <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna.</span>
                        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449069/2print_zszssh.jpg">
         <div class="details">
                           
                            <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna.</span>
                        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449086/2brand_identity_oo9udc.jpg">
         <div class="details">
                           
                            <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna.</span>
                        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449077/2graphic_design_obcmif.jpg">
         <div class="details">
                            
                            <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna.</span>
                        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449069/2print_zszssh.jpg">
         <div class="details">
                           
                            <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna.</span>
                        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449077/2graphic_design_obcmif.jpg">
         <div class="details">
                            
                            <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna.</span>
                        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449069/2print_zszssh.jpg">
         <div class="details">
                            
                            <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna.</span>
                        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449077/2graphic_design_obcmif.jpg">
         <div class="details">
                            
                            <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna.</span>
                        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449086/2brand_identity_oo9udc.jpg">
         <div class="details">
                           
                            <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna, Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. </span>
                        </div>
        </div>

   </div>
  </div>
```

I need each image, when hovered, to overlap and stand over the others and for the text to remain on the image. It also needs to be much smoother and not jump. Any assistance as to how I can rectify would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `z-index` to make the hover image always on the top and you may add `overflow:hidden` and `top:0` to the detail text :

```css
/* Partners page */

.masonry {
  /* Masonry container */
  column-count: 5;
}

.brick img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Gotham-Light';
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 3em auto;
}

.masonry {
  margin: 1.5em 0;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-column-gap: 1.5em;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em;
  column-gap: 1.5em;
  font-size: .85em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.brick {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Image words / text hover effect */

.brick {
  opacity: .99;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .brick .details {
  padding: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .7s ease;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .9), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  overflow:hidden;
}

.brick:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}

.brick:hover .details {
  opacity: 1;
}

.brick .details span {
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  /* 100px */
  -webkit-transition-property: top, opacity;
  transition-property: top, opacity;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.brick .details #title {
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.brick .details #info {
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.brick:focus:before,
.brick:focus span,
.brick:hover:before,
.brick:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
}

.brick:focus:before,
.brick:hover:before {
  top: 0;
  /* 50% */
}

.brick:focus span,
.brick:hover span {
  top: 0;
}

.brick:focus #title,
.brick:hover #title {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s;
  transition-delay: 0.25s;
}

.brick:focus #info,
.brick:hover #info {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s;
  transition-delay: 0.25s;
}


/* -------------------------   */
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="masonry">
    <div class="partner">
      <a href="index.html"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509810535/Certo-120x72_hrw5eq.png" style="width: 180px; height: 120px;" class="partimg"></a>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet
        dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449086/2brand_identity_oo9udc.jpg">
      <div class="details">

        <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449069/2print_zszssh.jpg">
      <div class="details">

        <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449077/2graphic_design_obcmif.jpg">
      <div class="details">

        <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449069/2print_zszssh.jpg">
      <div class="details">

        <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449086/2brand_identity_oo9udc.jpg">
      <div class="details">

        <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449077/2graphic_design_obcmif.jpg">
      <div class="details">

        <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449069/2print_zszssh.jpg">
      <div class="details">

        <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449077/2graphic_design_obcmif.jpg">
      <div class="details">

        <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449069/2print_zszssh.jpg">
      <div class="details">

        <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449077/2graphic_design_obcmif.jpg">
      <div class="details">

        <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449086/2brand_identity_oo9udc.jpg">
      <div class="details">

        <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna, Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. </span>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. How come it scales back a little after one second? Is there a way I can get the image just to scale up a little bit then scale back when I stop hovering? I'm really just trying to make the images stand out a little.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead it seems like a bug due to the scale transformation ... to avoid this i advice you to use the images as background of `.brick` element and keep the text inside it without absolute positon

Comment: Think it might just be a bug on codepen because when I've put the code on my site it works as I want it to.